# Why isn't C++ strtok() working for me?

Tags: c++, tokenize, strtok

The program is supposed to receive an input through cin, tokenize it, and then output each one to show me that it worked properly. It did not.

The program compiles with no errors, and takes an input, but fails to output anything.

What am I doing wrong?

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  string input_line;

  while(std::cin >> input_line){
    char* pch = (char*)malloc( sizeof( char ) *(input_line.length() +1) );

    char *p = strtok(pch, " ");
    while (p != NULL) {
      printf ("Token: %s\n", p);
      p = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

I followed the code example here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strtok/

Thanks.

Comment: As a side note, `sizeof(char)` is always 1 (by definition), and `new char[]` will avoid the need for `sizeof` altogether with any type, as well as pointer cast on the result.

Comment: Are you sure that you want `cin >> input_line` (reads one string, stop on whitespace) and not `getline(cin, input_line)` (read one string, stop on newline)?

Comment: ...and don't forget to free pch. Or better still, use an std::vector instead of a manually managed buffer

Comment: As another side note, you're mixing C++ and C rather badly.  Mixing stdio and stream I/O is rarely a good idea, and C++ has much better string-handling features than C.  Moreover, `strtok()` is a very badly designed function.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looks like you forget to copy the contents of `input_line` to pch:

```
strcpy(pch, input_line.c_str());
```

But I'm not sure why you're doing string tokenization anyway. Doing `cin >> input_line` will not read a line, but a token.. so you get tokens anyway?

Answer (score 5):

This is more of a correctness post, Hans has your problem.

The correct way to get a line of input is with `getline`:

```
std::string s;
std::getline(std::cin, s);
```

`std::cin` breaks at whitespace anyway, so if you typed `asd 123` and ran your code, `input_line` would first be "asd", then the second time in the loop "123" (without waiting for enter).

That said, an easy way to get your result is with a `stringstream`. Any time you explicitly allocate memory, especially with `malloc`, you're probably doing something the hard way. Here's one possible solution to tokenizing a string:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main(void)
{
    std::string input;
    std::getline(std::cin, input);

    std::stringstream ss(input);
    std::string token;
    while(std::getline(ss, token, ' '))
    {
        std::cout << token << "...";
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

If you really want to use `strtok`, you might do something like this:

```
#include <cstring>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main(void)
{
    std::string input;
    std::getline(std::cin, input);

    std::vector<char> buffer(input.begin(), input.end());
    buffer.push_back('\0');

    char* token = strtok(&buffer[0], " ");
    for (; token; token = strtok(0, " "))
    {
        std::cout << token << "...";
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Remember, manually memory management is bad. Use a `vector` for arrays, and you avoid leaks. (Which your code has!)

Answer (score 1):

You didn't initialize your string. Insert

```
strcpy(pch, input_line.c_str());
```

after the `malloc` line.

Answer (score 0):

Or use this:

```
pch = strdup(input_line.c_str());
```

Answer (score 0):

GMan's answer is probably better and more purely c++. This is more of a mix which specifically uses `strtok()`, since I think that was your goal.

I used `strdup()`/`free()` since it was the easiest way to copy the string. In the question you were leaking memory since you'd `malloc()` with no matching `free()`.

Also operator>> with the string will break on whitespace and so inappropriate for getting lines. Use `getline()` instead.

### token.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring> /* for strtok() and strdup() */
#include <cstdlib> /* for free() */

int main(int argc, char * argv[]){
    std::string line;

    while(getline(std::cin, line)){
        char *pch = strdup(line.c_str());

        char *p = strtok(pch, " ");

        while(p){
            std::cout<<"Token: "<<p<<std::endl;
            p = strtok(NULL, " ");
        }

        std::cout <<"End of line"<<std::endl;
        free(pch);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When you run this, you get what appears to be the correct result/

> $ printf 'Hi there, I like tokens\nOn new lines too\n\nBlanks are fine'|./token
>   Token: Hi
>   Token: there,
>   Token: I
>   Token: like
>   Token: tokens
>   End of line
>   Token: On
>   Token: new
>   Token: lines
>   Token: too
>   End of line
>   End of line
>   Token: Blanks
>   Token: are
>   Token: fine
>   End of line